# Python: CustomTkinter - returning varibles selected from combobox

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, combobox, customtkinter

I am new to python anf CustomTkinter and am having trouble with a few things.
I am trying to make a GUI whereby the user inputs certain data and the program takes these input and does various data analyses on them.

For example,
This is the code i'm currently working on:

```
import customtkinter
import os

import customtkinter as ctk

import tkinter


root = ctk.CTk()
ctk.set_default_color_theme("dark-blue")
ctk.set_appearance_mode("Dark")
root.title('Compression & Indentation Analysis Interface')
root.geometry("4000x1000")
frame = ctk.CTkFrame(master = root,fg_color="#A4C3C9")
# frame.pack(padx = 60, pady= 20, fill ="both", expand = True)
frame.grid(row = 0, column = 0)


def indenter_picker():
    if indenter_selection.get() == "0.5mm":
        indenter_D = 0.5
    if indenter_selection.get() == "1.0mm":
        indenter_D = 1.0
    print(indenter_D)


    return indenter_D



#select indenter size
indenter_size_label = ctk.CTkLabel(frame, text = "Select the Indenter Diameter (mm):", text_color= "black")
indenter_size_label.grid(row = 0 , column = 0,padx = 10, pady = 20)

indenter_options = ["0.5mm", "1.0mm"]
indenter_var = tkinter.StringVar()
indenter_selection = ctk.CTkComboBox(frame, values = indenter_options,fg_color="#EFF2F3",text_color= "black")
indenter_selection.grid(row = 0, column = 1, padx = 10,pady = 20)

#User to select button if happy with selection and save the variable selected
indenter_set_button = ctk.CTkButton(frame, text = "Set Indenter Value",fg_color="#EFF2F3",text_color= "black",command = indenter_picker)
indenter_set_button.grid(row = 0 , column = 2,padx = 10, pady = 20)


root.mainloop()
```

Here, I am trying to get the user to select an option from the combo box and if they are happy with the selection then select the button.

Once the button is selected, I want the program to check which option the user has selected and to make a variable "indenter_D" equal to a value depending on the selection.

I want to then use indenter_D outside the command function for further data analysis. However, I cant seem to return this value for further use!

Does anyone know how to take variables selected out from the interface for data manipulation?

Edit 14 dec 23:
Here I have tried to make "indenter_D" a global variable and have called it after making the button function.

```
import os

import customtkinter as ctk

import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk


root = ctk.CTk()
ctk.set_default_color_theme("dark-blue")
ctk.set_appearance_mode("Dark")
root.title('Compression & Indentation Analysis Interface')
root.geometry("4000x1000")
frame = ctk.CTkFrame(master = root,fg_color="#A4C3C9")
# frame.pack(padx = 60, pady= 20, fill ="both", expand = True)
frame.grid(row = 0, column = 0)


def indenter_picker():
    global indenter_D
    if indenter_selection.get() == "0.5mm":
        indenter_D = 0.5
    if indenter_selection.get() == "1.0mm":
        indenter_D = 1.0

    return indenter_D




#Pre-loading or Grpah method checks

# Path_checkvar = customtkinter.StringVar(value = "")

#select indenter size
indenter_size_label = ctk.CTkLabel(frame, text = "Select the Indenter Diameter (mm):", text_color= "black")
indenter_size_label.grid(row = 0 , column = 0,padx = 10, pady = 20)

indenter_options = ["0.5mm", "1.0mm"]
indenter_var = tk.StringVar()
indenter_selection = ctk.CTkComboBox(frame, values = indenter_options,fg_color="#EFF2F3",text_color= "black",variable = indenter_var)
# indenter_selection = ttk.Combobox(frame, values = indenter_options,textvariable = indenter_var )
indenter_selection.grid(row = 0, column = 1, padx = 10,pady = 20)

indenter_set_button = ctk.CTkButton(frame, text = "Set Indenter Value",command = indenter_picker,fg_color="#EFF2F3",text_color= "black")
# indenter_set_button = ttk.Button(frame, text = "Set Indenter Value",command = indenter_picker)
indenter_set_button.grid(row = 0 , column = 2,padx = 10, pady = 20)
indenter_D = indenter_picker()
print(indenter_D)


root.mainloop()
```

Comment: For your case, the simple way is to declare `indenter_D` as a global variable by adding `global indenter_D` at the beginning of `indenter_picker()`.  Or call `indenter_picker()` to get the value inside another function.

Comment: I've just tried making it a global variable, however the script doesn't recognise the variable if I call it outside the function:                                                this is the  error I get: print(indenter_D)
          ^^^^^^^^^^
NameError: name 'indenter_D' is not defined. Did you mean: 'indenter_var'?

Comment: You need to execute `indenter_picker()` in order to create the global variable, or you need to initialize the global variable.

Comment: Isnt it excuted here in this line as a command: indenter_set_button = ctk.CTkButton(frame, text = "Set Indenter Value",fg_color="#EFF2F3",text_color= "black",command = indenter_picker)

Comment: Where did you call `print(indenter_D)`? It is better to update your code in the question so that we can know how you access the variable outside the function.

Comment: I have updated the code!

Comment: When `print(indenter_D)` is executed, `indenter_D` is not created because `indenter_picker()` has not been executed yet.

Comment: If i were to call the indenter_picker() function outside of the CTk.Button command, then it cannot understand it. (See where I have placed it in my edited code)

Comment: I don't understand why you want to access the variable at that moment.

Comment: my goal is to ask the user to input some data. Here, I want them to select the indenter diameter from the options "0.5mm" and 1.0mm. Once they have selected the value required, and pressed the "set value" button, I want the script to return which option they have selected (Once they have pressed the button). I want this to be returned because indenter_D is going to be a variable used later in my code. for this example lets just say we want to use this diameter to find the area of a circle. So the user selects the indenter Size and I use this info to find the area

Comment: Then you should access the variable in another function that may be triggered by another button, not the way in your updated code.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.